# How can I shorten the Long Code output in questions and answers and display scrollbars?

Tags: support, code-formatting

There are some questions and answers that have very log output that is condensed with scrollbars.

Is there a formatting method to control how much is displayed between the scrolling.  I believe some post appears to be easy to skip the formatted sections and view the descriptions and details of the post, and some appear to have very long formatted parts.

If the appearance is incidental, and there is no control over how to put smaller chunks in a view at a time, then at least I can stop trying to figure it out if it doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance for any comments on this.

Comment: I looked briefly through couple formatting posts on meta.stackexchange.com, didn't really find anything particularly useful.  If it's for your own question, you could use a pastebin , like paste.ubuntu.com , but I don't think it's a good idea to use that on someone else's question

Comment: I totally agree about the pastebin on someone else's question.  I'm sure with your experience, if the feature existed, you would have used it.  So it might have been my imagination of a cleanup I had saw in a question some time ago.  Maybe it was a difference cleanup that gave that appearance.  I'll count the lines display lines and if it's less than 38 between the scollbars, I'll update this thread.